# Oozie frequency 1 minute interval? How to set up

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

This can be a simple question, but I need to know.

How to set up oozie coordinator frequency at 1 minute frequency?

I need to run a shell script 1 minute interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oozie Frequency representation,

```
frequency="${coord:minutes(1)}"
```

**Update:**

Cron Style representation,

```
frequency="0/1 * * * *"
```

Comment: I need cron style frequency. like frequency = 30 * * * *

Comment: For every 1 minute 0/1 * * * *

Comment: thanks for your answer. This part is working. In our oozie environment somewhere it is set maximum frequency = 5,  `getting error   E1003: Invalid coordinator application attributes, Coordinator job with frequency [1] minutes is faster than allowed maximum of 5 minutes   (oozie.service.coord.check.maximum.frequency is set to true)` , Can you help to set this to 1

Comment: Add this property `<property><name>oozie.service.coord.check.maximum.frequency</name><value>false</value></property>` to your oozie configuration file (oozie-site.xml/oozie-default.xml). But changing this is not recommended.

Comment: Appreciating your help @fraklinsjio. It is fine now.

Comment: `frequency="* * * * *"` also works for 1 min interval. Is it OK to set `frequency="0/2 * * * *"` fro 2 min interval?

Comment: Thanks for the added info. Yes you can do that.

Comment: Thanks for your response.